# Why beam something dangerous into space?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-transporter

When the Enterprise crew are dealing with an explosive situation (literally), they sometimes beam the bomb, overloading phasor, maniacal android, etc into space ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeTcTRp0GkY)).  Why do this?  I mean, why rematerialize the item at all? It seems that they would be able to effectively neutralize the threat without releasing all that pent-up energy (or aggression). Maybe they could even do so in a more useful way, using it to power a reactor or steam engine or giant hamster wheel rather than wasting it on empty space. Has this ever been addressed?

Has there been an instance in the series, movies or even novels where something or someone has specifically not been rematerialized in order to neutralize a threat?

Comment: Because it requires special permission from a senior officer to use the perma-kill facility on the transporters

Comment: Couldn't stuff be held in the transporter buffer for a few moments while permission is given?

Comment: There's always been the question of how the hell they beam _energy_ at all.  But I would suggest that an explosion is a massive expenditure of energy - trying to keep that much energy in the buffers even for a few seconds would overload the transporter power systems. It'd still explode. Instant transfer to somewhere external sheds all that energy immediately.  Since the transporters are designed to remake whatever they transport, letting it rematerialize in space is faster and safer.

Comment: @Tim Once it's converted to energy it's basically just information. It's in a suspended state and can't explode.

Comment: I really did try to look for a similar question, but I certainly didn't think to look for a question about Nomad from TOS.  That answer perfectly addresses this question.